# Difference between STS and Identity Provider (IdP)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, ws-federation

I was trying to implement Ws-Federation protocol for my application. When researching for this STS and IdP are used along with few other buzzwords. I know Federation is between two security realm to trust each other to access resource. And IdP was the source of identity about the user and IdP's can use SAML , OAUTH , OIDC and others during authentication of the user. What role does STS play here.
Explain all Buzzwords like IdPs, SPs , relying party , Federation and STS in much more clear way and with some analogy
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the Microsoft world (since you are asking about WS-Fed):

- IDP - handles authentication and issues tokens, either SAML or JWT (OIDC). Examples are ADFS or Entra ID. (WS-Fed issues SAML tokens)
- CP - claims provider - the instance in the IDP that handles a particular RP request. In ADFS, this would run the claims rules
- RP - The application, e.g. ASP.NET, that connects to the CP via WS-Fed
- SP - this is the equivalent of an RP in the SAML world
- Federation - connecting two IDPs together so, e.g. users in an ADFS tenant can authenticate to an Entra ID application
- STS - security token system - the part of an IDP that issues tokens

I have also seen STS used as an intermediary IDP, e.g. RP --> ADFS --> Entra ID as opposed to RP --> Entra ID. The ADFS here would be the STS.